# Export SQLite3 to CSV with Python. sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I need some help with my code, because I cannot understand why is giving to me this error (sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error).

I want to export a database.db to database.csv from Python, and this code works fine on sqlite3, but when I typed on Python3 with cur.execute() this error appears.

Now this is my code where the bug is

```
fname = input('Name for the csv?\n> ')
cur.execute('.headers on')
cur.execute('.mode csv')
cur.execute(f'.output {fname}.csv')
```

I searched on other forums but I think that this is a particular case.
I hope somebody can help me fixing the error, or giving me an alternative way to export the database to csv with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. These commands work only within the sqlite executable and can't be used like regular SQL commands or pragrmas. What you could do in Python is run a shell command.